# Cadastro com Validação

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

atualmente o meu sistema possui Pessoa e Time, uma pessoa ja pode criar um Time, definindo alguns atributos(nome e senhaTime).

Agora, tenho como objetivo criar um metodo "Entrar em Time" onde uma pessoa qualquer vai entrar em um time ja existente passando o ID e a SenhaTime.

Ja fiz alguns metodos de cadastro, mas estou com duvida em como fazer essa validação se a SenhaTime informada pela Pessoa confere com a SenhaTime do ID informado.

TimeBean:

```
public void entrarEmTime(){
            getPessoaTimeDAO().cadastrar(getPessoaTimeMembro(getPessoaBean().usuarioLogado(), getTime()));
            limpaTela();
    }

public PessoaTime getPessoaTimeMembro(Pessoa pessoa, Time time){
        PessoaTime p = new PessoaTime();
        p.setPessoa(pessoa);
        p.setTime(time);
        p.setCargo(Cargo.MEMBRO);
        return p;
    }
```

entrarTime.xhtml:

```
<h:form class="form-label" id="entrarTime">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="thread" class="col-md-2">ID Time:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <h:inputText value="#{timeMB.time.id}" type="nome"
                                                    class="form-control" id="nome"
                                                    placeholder="Adicione um nome ao seu time" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="description" class="col-md-2">Senha do
                                                Time:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <h:inputSecret value="#{timeMB.time.senhaTime}"
                                                    type="password" class="form-control" id="senha"
                                                    placeholder="Senha do seu Time" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <h:commandButton action="#{timeMB.entrarEmTime()}"
                                                value="Entrar"
                                                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rounded btn-shadow" />
                                        </div>
                                    </h:form>
```

Model:

PessoaModel:

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id_Pessoa")
    private Integer id;

    @Column()
    private String nomeUsuario;

    @Column()
    private String senhaUsuario;

    @Column()
    private String nomeCompleto;

    @Column()
    private String email;

    @Column()
    private Integer idade;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pessoa", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<PessoaTime> listaPessoaTime;
```

TimeModel:

```
@Entity
public class Time implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id_Time")
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String senhaTime;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "time",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<PessoaTime> listaPessoaTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="time",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<CampeonatoTime> listaCampeonatoTime;
```

PessoaTimeModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa_time")
public class PessoaTime implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="id_PessoaTime")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_time")
    private Time time;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Cargo cargo;
```

Comment: Só para confirmar, esse cadastro de SenhaTime e ID ficam salvos em Banco de Dados ou em um Array?

Comment: Banco de dados. Se quiser posso colocar as classes de MODEL.

Comment: Cada ID recebe uma SenhaTime especifica certo? Essas informações são salvas em duas tabelas diferentes no BD também?

Comment: Sim, cada ID tem uma senha. Salvo em suas respectivas tabelas.

Comment: Olá, Rafael! Coloque as classes de model também, por favor.

Comment: Adicionado @Dherik

Answer (score 0):

Não tratarei de códigos aqui, mas apenas ideias.

Você captura o Id do Time e a senha em um objeto no seu ManagedBean.
Em um método, você faz uma busca no banco de dados pelo id do time e armazena em outra variável temporária (escopo do método), faz as comparações necessárias.

---

Outra opção seria você ter uma Lista de Times no seu ManagedBean do JSF, exibí-los na tela através de um combobox na tela (se não forem muitos registros) em um campo TimeSelecionado no ManagedBean. Então compara o objeto selecionado com os da sua lista.